# Find out what line of code my app is currently running in Visual Studio's debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

When I'm running an app in debug mode with Visual Studio, is there a way that I can find out what line of code is currently being processed? By this I mean, is there a tool that works kind of like setting a breakpoint, but you don't have to set a breakpoint - you can just find out at any point in time what line of code is being executed?

The reason for this, is that sometimes you may want to debug intermittent hangs in your app. If your running in debug mode, and your app hangs, it would be useful to immediately find out what line of code it last processed, without having to plan ahead by setting breakpoints or trace calls.

Comment: I've been using Visual Studio for years and never knew the answer to this. Thanks for posting the question! (Also, you should mark this answered.)

Comment: Bingo ! I was stumped , having used vs for some years I never knew I could do this... drat! Thanks!

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Press the Pause Button ("||").

Comment: Sorry but where is paise button ?

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur, It's where all the other Visual studio buttons are, on the button bar just below the menu bar.  It has 2 vertical lines like this: " || ". It should be between the run button (green triangle) and the stop button (red square).

Comment: If the button bar is not visible this can also be found in the Debug section of the menu.

Comment: 10 years later, but if you do not see the butter. Go to View -> Toolbars and enable the "Standard" toolbar .

Comment: Visual Studio Named it as **Break All** Button! ShortCut as (Ctrl+Alt+Break)