# SQL Server connection freezes after a few hundred loops

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

In a C#.NET Core 5 project I use `System.Data.SQLClient` 4.8.2 to connect to a SQL Server 11.

This code works fine.

```
    public List<Contract> ReadDBView(Contract contract)
    {
        List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract> { };
        try
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            builder.DataSource = "server01";
            builder.UserID = "user1";
            builder.Password = "SecretPassword";
            builder.InitialCatalog = "archiv1";
            String sql = "SELECT name, group_name, group_country_code, FROM[dbo].[GROUPS] where number like '%" + contract.Number.ToString() + "'";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            contract.DealerName = reader["name"].ToString();
                            contract.GroupName = reader["group_name"].ToString();
                            contract.Country = reader["group_country_code"].ToString();
                            contracts.Add(contract);
                        }
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        return contracts;
    }
```

But after a while it freezes - any idea how to prevent a freeze ?

The return value is sometimes null. As I have done a long time nothing with C# any hint on the code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I highly recommend you fix that major security flaw in your code; SQL Injection should have died by now. There's a reason we prefer parameters.

Comment: How often do you run it? Do you have any other SQL statements against the same table?

Comment: @Larnu can you share a link to a good example

Comment: It is very important to know [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: @jgauffin I'll check that but probably not more than 5000 times

Comment: @M.Mohabbati thanks for the Link

Comment: Share the *exception* you faced.

Comment: @M.Mohabbati it does not show any error, maybe silently running / waiting for something. I have to debug/ change the code to see more

Comment: First of all,  the return value can never be `null`, at worst it returns an empty list. If you really observe `null`s something else is going on. Second, the performance of this code depends on what's in `contract.Number` -- as this code uses a `LIKE '%...'`, it won't be able to use indexes effectively, and the number of records returned (and hence also how long the query will run) depends on the input parameter. I recommend adding some logging to see if there's a particular value that triggers slowness.

Comment: 5000 times, in what time span?

Comment: @Jgauffin. It loops so every call takes a bout a second once done, the next one. Only a single one at the time. Actually it looks like it is just super slow not really freezing as in doing nothing

Comment: `SELECT name, group_name, group_country_code, FROM[dbo].[GROUPS]` This is not valid tsql and will generate a syntax error. Perhaps a type added during posting? But it might be better to address your actual goal. How many rows are in the table you are selecting from? The name does not imply many, so my concern is that you are selecting the same rows over and over and over and then adding many duplicates into your list.

Comment: So the pool is drained as the are several pending queries of the same type. Improve the query execution time or increase the job interval.

Comment: thank you all. It is solved now and yes the code simply need updates for latest C# version to isolate issues better and finally be  a bit more verbose through logging to see it where it is slowly working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider returning a named ValueTuple

The following example uses an existing table that doesn't match yours's but demonstrates one way to find out if something is throwing an exception. Using Console.WriteLine is fine for debugging (better to use Debug.WriteLine) but why not setup for production.

- Consider adding logging as per @jeroen Mostert recommended
- Table is not setup index wise for a like condition so it's not efficient. The point is to figure out if there is an exception thrown or not.
- C#9, .NET Core 5 syntax is used e.g. `using` declaration rather than statement body.

Backend code

```
public class SqlOperations
{
    public static string ConnectionString =
        "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaginationExample;Integrated Security=True";


    public static (List<Contract>, Exception exception) ReadDBView(string firstNameValue)
    {
        List<Contract> contracts = new();

        var selectStatement = 
            "SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Balance " + 
            "FROM dbo.LotsOfData " + 
            "WHERE FirstName LIKE @FirstNameLike;";

        try
        {
            using var cn = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };
            using var cmd = new SqlCommand() { Connection = cn, CommandText = selectStatement };

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstNameLike", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = firstNameValue;
            
            cn.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (!reader.HasRows) return (contracts, null);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                contracts.Add(new Contract()
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    FirstName = reader.GetString(1),
                    LastName = reader.GetString(2),
                        
                    Balance = reader.IsDBNull("Balance") ? 
                        (decimal?)null : 
                        reader.GetDecimal("Balance")
                            
                });
            }

            return (contracts, null);

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return (null, exception);
        }

        
    }
}

// place in own file
public class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Balance { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";

}
```

Using a unit test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void LargeLike()
{
    var (contracts, exception) = SqlOperations.ReadDBView("%nia");

    if (contracts.Count > 0 && exception is null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(contracts.Count);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exception is not null ? exception.Message : "No matches");
    }
}
```

Syntax for `using`

```
public static void UsingExample()
{
    // C#9, .NET Core 5 syntax
    using var cn1 = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString };

    // .NET 4.8 syntax
    using (var cn2 = new SqlConnection() { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
    {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. What Do you mean by "C#9, .NET Core 5 syntax is used e.g. using declaration rather than statement body" ?

Comment: See the last code block in my reply to see the difference.

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration

Comment: What line does it "freeze" on? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508792/109122  may not work on a synchronous hang)

Comment: @KarenPayne thanks, I would have to study the answer before I'am able to use it.

Comment: @user3732793 I would expect nothing less, always wise to not simple copy-paste without understanding the code.